# What will my soon-to-be born son's suffix be?

Tags: names

There is some debate amongst my family currently on how to name my soon-to-be born son:

For ease of typing, I'm going to use first names only.

My grandpa is named Joe. He has a 2 sons one born in 1960 Joe JR, and one in 1962 John.

I was born in 1991 to John and named after my grandpa. I am Joe II.

My uncle had a son in 2000 and continued his name. He is Joe III.

Now I, Joe II, am having a son in 2022 and plan to also continue the name. What will my son's suffix be? III or IV?

My take:
My uncle Joe JR and his son Joe III are in their own line of the family tree. When my father named me after my grandpa he started a different line and my son will be the III in that line.

What are the thoughts on this? I've struggled to find a similar example as in my family online.

Comment: Is this really about parenting? Sounds more like law, etiquette, history, almost anything but parenting.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, this is all up to you and your partner. What control or input you give your family is up to you as well. There is no such thing as a right or wrong way to name a child (so long as you do so with thought for the child, and your local laws).

If you want to see your son as third in a line, do so.

Comment: Yeah that was basically my takeaway from the reading online.